# Ошибка ajax post запроса к серверу "net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, .net

На странице "Index.cshtml" проекта Web-application C# есть функция ajax, которая по нажатию на кнопку должна загружать файл на сервер:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        import { error } from "jquery";
    
        $("#btnUpload").click(function () {
                        var data = new FormData();
                        var files = $("#uploadFile").get(0).files;
                        // Add the uploaded image content to the form data collection
                        if (files.length > 0) {
                            data.append("UploadedFile", files[0]);
                        }
                        data.append("wayFile", $("#wayFile").val());  //Other data
                        var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "http://localhost:44367/api/FileApi/UploadFile",
                            contentType: false,
                            processData: false,
                            data: data,
                            success: function (response) {
                                alert('File uploaded');
                                console.log(response);
                            },
                            error: function (result, status, er) {
                                alert("error: " + result + " status: " + status + " er:" + er);
                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                    });
</script>
```

На неё отвечает следующий контроллер:

```
public class FileApiController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/FileApi/UploadFile")]
        public void UploadFile()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var fileName in HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys)
                    {
                        HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[fileName];
                        if (file != null)
                        {

                            FileDTO fileDTO = new FileDTO();

                            fileDTO.FileActualName = file.FileName;
                            fileDTO.FileExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                            fileDTO.ContentType = file.ContentType;

                            //Generate a unique name using Guid
                            fileDTO.FileUniqueName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                            //Get physical path of our folder where we want to save images
                            var rootPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles");

                            var fileSavePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(rootPath, fileDTO.FileUniqueName + fileDTO.FileExt);

                            
                            file.SaveAs(fileSavePath);

                            //Save File Meta data in Database

                            FileModel.SaveFileInDB(fileDTO);

                        }
                    }//end of foreach
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { }
            }
            var age = HttpContext.Current.Request["wayFile"];
        }      
}
```

Но выдает следующею ошибку:

> POST http://localhost:44367/api/FileApi/UploadFile
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET send    @   jquery-3.4.1.js:9837
> ajax  @   jquery-3.4.1.js:9434 (anonymous)    @   Index:82
> dispatch  @   jquery-3.4.1.js:5237 elemData.handle    @   jquery-3.4.1.js:5044

Добавил в контроллер С# обрабатывающий данный запрос код `HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` - ошибка пропала, но действий (загрузки) не происходит

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("api/FileApi/UploadFile")]
        public void UploadFile()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var fileName in HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys)
                    {
                        HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[fileName];
                        if (file != null)
                        {

                            FileDTO fileDTO = new FileDTO();

                            fileDTO.FileActualName = file.FileName;
                            fileDTO.FileExt = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                            fileDTO.ContentType = file.ContentType;

                            //Generate a unique name using Guid
                            fileDTO.FileUniqueName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                            //Get physical path of our folder where we want to save images
                            var rootPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles");

                            var fileSavePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(rootPath, fileDTO.FileUniqueName + fileDTO.FileExt);

                            // Save the uploaded file to "UploadedFiles" folder
                            file.SaveAs(fileSavePath);

                            //Save File Meta data in Database
                            FileModel.SaveFileInDB(fileDTO);
                        }
                    }//end of foreach
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { }
            }//end of if count > 0
            var age = HttpContext.Current.Request["wayFile"];
        }
```

Перeписал ajax немного по другому - как просто отдельную функцию, а в button прописал акшен onclic, повесил на него эту функцию. Не знаю почему, но так заработало

```
<input type="button" id="btnUpload" value="Upload" onclick="RequestUpload()"/>


function RequestUpload(){
            var data = new FormData();
            var files = $("#uploadFile").get(0).files;
            // Add the uploaded image content to the form data collection
            if (files.length > 0) {
                data.append("UploadedFile", files[0]);
            }
            data.append("infoFile", $("#infoFile").val());  //Other data
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:6141/api/FileApi/UploadFile",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: data,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('File uploaded');
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function (result, status, er) {
                    alert("error: " + result + " status: " + status + " er:" + er);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: А POST по адресу `http://localhost:44367/api/FileApi/UploadFile` с обычной веб формы пробовали?

Comment: Без ajax или как?

Comment: Хоть как-нибудь, хоть через Postman

Comment: Нет, сейчас поставлю Postman и попробую

Comment: Я к тому, что проблема скорее всего в том, что сервер не принимает запрос, а не в том, что с AJAX что-то не так. Выглядит он кстати нормально.

Comment: Да, вы правы, у приложения оказывается 2 URL - http://localhost:6141/   and  https://localhost:44367/. 2-му нужно было добавить s in https

Comment: Теперь когда шлю на  localhost:6141 выдает ошибки: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:6141/api/FileApi/UploadFile' from origin 'https://localhost:44367' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
:6141/api/FileApi/UploadFile:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: Добавьте в ответ от сервера заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` [ссылка](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Comment: Добавил в контроллер С# обрабатывающий данный запрос код "HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");" - ошибка пропала, но действий (загрузки) не происходит